# MPI-IO deadlock using MPI_File_write_all

Tags: io, mpi, deadlock

My **MPI** code deadlocks when I run this simple code on **512** processes on a cluster. I am far from the memory limit. If I increase the number of procesess to **2048**, which is far too many for this problem, the code runs again. The deadlock occurs in the line containing the `MPI_File_write_all`.

Any suggestions?

```
int count = imax*jmax*kmax;

// CREATE THE SUBARRAY
MPI_Datatype subarray;
int totsize [3] = {kmax, jtot, itot};
int subsize [3] = {kmax, jmax, imax};
int substart[3] = {0, mpicoordy*jmax, mpicoordx*imax};
MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, totsize, subsize, substart, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &subarray);
MPI_Type_commit(&subarray);

// SET THE VALUE OF THE GRID EQUAL TO THE PROCESS ID FOR CHECKING
if(mpiid == 0) std::printf("Setting the value of the array\n");
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
  u[i] = (double)mpiid;

// WRITE THE FULL GRID USING MPI-IO
if(mpiid == 0) std::printf("Write the full array to disk\n");
char filename[] = "u.dump";
MPI_File fh;
if(MPI_File_open(commxy, filename, MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY | MPI_MODE_EXCL, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh))
  return 1;

// select noncontiguous part of 3d array to store the selected data
MPI_Offset fileoff = 0; // the offset within the file (header size)
char name[] = "native";

if(MPI_File_set_view(fh, fileoff, MPI_DOUBLE, subarray, name, MPI_INFO_NULL))
  return 1;

if(MPI_File_write_all(fh, u, count, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE))
  return 1;

if(MPI_File_close(&fh))
  return 1;
```

Comment: What are the values of `imax`, `jmax` and `kmax`? Also the values of `jtot` and `itot`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right upon quick inspection.  I would suggest that you let your MPI-IO library help tell you what's wrong:  instead of returning from error, why don't you at least display the error?  Here's some code that might help:

```
static void handle_error(int errcode, char *str)
{
        char msg[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
        int resultlen;
        MPI_Error_string(errcode, msg, &resultlen);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", str, msg);
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
}
```

Is MPI_SUCCESS guaranteed to be 0? I'd rather see

```
 errcode = MPI_File_routine();
 if (errcode != MPI_SUCCESS) handle_error(errcode, "MPI_File_open(1)");
```

Put that in and if you are doing something tricky like setting a file view with offsets that are not monotonically non-decreasing,  the error string might suggest what's wrong.

Comment: The code doesn't return a value, because it deadlocks. How am I supposed to get a return error?

Comment: i guess i do not understand your deadlock.  Every single mpi process is stuck inside an MPI routine?  More likely one or two returned error, and the remainder are waiting for their cohort in the communicator to participate in the routine.

Comment: I don't understand this deadlock either. None of the processes returns anything. I have implemented your suggestion, but the MPI just completely hangs in the writing.

Comment: Huh.  Then maybe you are seeing a bug in the mpi implementation? When you hit deadlock, you could attach GDB to one of the processes and see what it's trying to do.  a backtrace from rank 0, rank N, and some random rank in between would be helpful, if not to stackoverflow, then to your MPI vendor.

Comment: I have reported the problem there as well, probably you are right. The interesting fact is that the deadlock occurs going below a minimal number of processors (512) on one system (SuperMUC, IBM/Intel) and going above a certain number of processes (4096) on the other (Juqueen / BG Q), which hints me to a setting. I will contact them and report here the cause, such that other users with the same problem have the full information.